# Leaflet: Fractional and irregular zoom levels from own tiles {z}

Tags: javascript, leaflet, proj4js

I'm using my own tile images to display in Leaflet. I know that it's possible to use fractional zoom levels, e. g. {1, 1.25, 1.5} so that Leaflet automatically enlarges the tiles according to the fraction. What I want to do, though, is to use tiles that are *provided* with fractional zoom levels. This is to add detail without quadrupling number of tiles.

An example:

- {z} = 3; {x}_max = 4; 16 tiles
- {z} = 4; {x}_max = 8; 64 tiles
- {z} = 5; {x}_max = 16; 256 tiles
- {z} = 5.39; {x}_max = 42; 1764 tiles

> 'http://{s}.somedomain.com/blabla/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

Zoom is given by directory name {z}.

If I name my directory with 5.39, it won't work. Depending on how I set maxZoom, it uses {z} = 5.39 as {z} = 6 (meaning it zooms to the wrong position) or none at all. Is it possible to get it to work with fractional numbers?

And, other than that, are irregular deltas between the zoom levels possible, e. g. {1, 1.2, 1.8, 2, 3.7, 5} ...?

Hope there's a solution to it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You would probably be interested in Leaflet repository [Feature Request #5641](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5641), [Pull Request #6118](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/6118) and their related threads.

Comment: Thank you! The Proj4leaflet plugin is interesting because it has a resolution option when defining the CRS – which is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I'd like to use L.CRS.Simple because I'm rendering a [non-geographical map](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html). This doesn't seem to be easily possible with Proj4Leaflet, or is it?